# Laravel 5. How I can save and take back values of Session

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I try save after log in of user, values in session database. I try use this code to validate login and put in session.

```PHP
   protected function login(Request $Request){
       $var = $Request->session()->all();
       return dd($var);   

       $user = Model\Account::where('username',$Request['username'])->first();
       if(isset($user)){
           if (Hash::check($Request['password'], $user->password))
                {
                    $Request->Session()->put('usuarios',$user);
                    return view('aluno/showActivities');
                }
           else{
               return dd('Invalid password.');
           }
       } 
       else{
           return dd('User doesn't exists.'); 
       }
    }
```

OBS:  I use a controller for execute login. This Route are defined like code in down.

```html
Route::post('/new/login',['as' => 'authRegister', 'uses' => 'UserController@login',function () {
    return Response::json(['Fail' => true], 404);
}] );
```

After login validation, the laravel did save this line in database.

[image: Image of database line]

He doesn't save user_id. How i can save this information? 
Other problem is how i can take back the informations of session ? In method get I tried use $Request->session()->get('usuarios'), but returned null.

var_dump($user) =

```html
yes. See the result.

object(App\Model\Account)#198 (23) { ["table":protected]=> string(7) "account" ["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql" ["fillable":protected]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "email" [1]=> string(8) "password" [2]=> string(8) "username" } ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["attributes":protected]=> array(8) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["email"]=> string(20) "thiagothgb@gmail.com" ["password"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$yFZDFHH2tr6OeoRtEShSmOsX99TQ7e.o5Tb2mJ7sA4tNZEXr4s3tG" ["username"]=> string(10) "thiagothgb" ["deleted_at"]=> NULL ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2016-04-23 17:20:10" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2016-04-23 17:20:10" ["user_id"]=> int(6) } ["original":protected]=> array(8) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["email"]=> string(20) "thiagothgb@gmail.com" ["password"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$yFZDFHH2tr6OeoRtEShSmOsX99TQ7e.o5Tb2mJ7sA4tNZEXr4s3tG" ["username"]=> string(10) "thiagothgb" ["deleted_at"]=> NULL ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2016-04-23 17:20:10" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2016-04-23 17:20:10" ["user_id"]=> int(6) } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) }
```

Comment: can you dump your this variable `$user` and show me the result array ? add dump result into question

Comment: yes. See the result.

Comment: I am asking, show me the results

Comment: sorry man. The array is so big to coment, so I put in end of question. See end lines of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, and check whether you get the session values or not.

```
$user = Model\Account::where('username',$Request['username'])->first();
$Request->Session()->put('usuarios',$user->toArray());
echo "<pre>";
 print_r($Request->Session()->get('usuarios'));
echo "</pre>";
die();
```

show me your results

Comment: <pre>array:8 [▼
  "id" => 4
  "email" => "thiagothgb@gmail.com"
  "password" => "$2y$10$yFZDFHH2tr6OeoRtEShSmOsX99TQ7e.o5Tb2mJ7sA4tNZEXr4s3tG"
  "username" => "thiagothgb"
  "deleted_at" => null
  "created_at" => "2016-04-23 17:20:10"
  "updated_at" => "2016-04-23 17:20:10"
  "user_id" => 6
] </pre>

Comment: nice, how I can take the session ID of array session store or put the user ID in table of session?

Comment: Store {#172 ▼
  #id: "2ed46602c6676481446c3eb5d800c49b8f623c07" // this camp
  #name: "laravel_session"
  #attributes: array:4 [▶]
  #bags: []
  #metaBag: MetadataBag {#173 ▶}
  #bagData: array:1 [▶]
  #handler: DatabaseSessionHandler {#171 ▶}
  #started: true
}

Comment: please add your queries/dumped results under your question in proper formatting, So I can understanding whats going

Answer (score 0):

now i understand. I modifield controller by:

```html
protected function VerificaSessao(Request $Request){
        if ($Request->session()){
            
            if ($Request->session()->has('usuarios')){
                
                return view('aluno/showActivities');
            }
            else{
                return dd('not have session');
            }
            
        }
        else{
            return dd('not have session');
        }
    }
```

And acess test on other browser and I looked the result. It not redirected to view "Aluno/showActivities". This Works. Thank you for help. Have a good night